# Upgrade glibc 2.17 to 2.19+ on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, glibc

First of all, Dropbox emailed me saying that I must upgrade glibc to 2.19+, otherwise Dropbox will not run.Then I follow the steps below to upgrade glibc.

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.28.tar.gz
tar –zxvf glibc-2.28.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.28
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin
```

Then I encountered the following error.

```
...
checking version of sed... 4.2.2, ok
checking for gawk... gawk
checking version of gawk... 4.0.2, ok
checking for bison... bison
checking version of bison... 3.0.4, ok
checking if gcc -B/usr/bin/ is sufficient to build libc... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for python3... python3
configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make compiler
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

Help me Please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=68050&sid=0f20f84d74e327a921b0cd581352fe43&start=10#p287875). There is a workaround for this problem, basically by cheating Dropbox to think that the glibc version is 2.19, when it is actually 2.17:

> Create dropboxcheat.c with this code:

```
const char *gnu_get_libc_version (void) {
        return "2.19"; }
```

> compile the cheat .so

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o dropboxcheat.so dropboxcheat.c
```

> move the .so to /usr/local/lib64/ add this line in dropbox.py, right
>   before subprocess.Popen....., in function start_dropbox

```
os.environ['LD_PRELOAD'] = "/usr/local/lib64/dropboxcheat.so"
```

> Run dropbox normally and it should ask to relogin.

Credit to **Pablo** for this solution.

I haven't tried it myself yet, but plan on doing so early next week. Let me know if this works out.

Comment: Thanks bro! It's work! Credit to **Pablo** for this solution and thanks for your share! Thank you very much! @Shovalt